How to obtain standardized residuals for clustered data in lavaan?
I am facing a problem concerning the output of standardized residuals for a fitted lavaan (sem)-object. As far as I do not include “cluster = ” in the fitting function, I can easily obtain the standardized residuals
But, as soon as include the cluster-argument (to take into account clustered data and correct the standard errors), I got this error message:
Fehler in Q %% ACOV.obs[[g]] : verlangt numerische/komplexe Matrix/Vektor-Argumente*
I played around with the Demo.twolevel-data included in lavaan, since I first thought it could be a problem with my data, but same here:
##packages
library(lavaan)

##models
# a) without cluster-variable
model <- '
fw =~ y1 + 1*y2 + y3
fw ~ x1 + x2 + x3
'
fit3 <- sem(model, data = Demo.twolevel)
summary(fit3, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)

lavResiduals(fit3, zstat = TRUE, se = TRUE) #works fine

Output:

lavResiduals(fit3o, zstat = TRUE, se = TRUE)#works fine
$type
[1] "cor.bentler"
$cov
y1     y2     y3     x1     x2     x3
y1  0.079
y2  0.016 -0.081
y3  0.075 -0.074  0.000
x1  0.025 -0.032  0.015  0.000
x2  0.026 -0.030  0.011  0.000  0.000
x3  0.011 -0.015  0.007  0.000  0.000  0.000
$cov.se
y1    y2    y3    x1    x2    x3
y1 0.010
y2 0.003 0.010
y3 0.010 0.009 0.000
x1 0.010 0.010 0.012 0.000
x2 0.010 0.010 0.012 0.000 0.000
x3 0.010 0.010 0.013 0.000 0.000 0.000
$cov.z
y1     y2     y3     x1     x2     x3
y1  7.918
y2  4.800 -7.918
y3  7.253 -8.040  0.000
x1  2.406 -3.153  1.247  0.000
x2  2.520 -2.948  0.845  0.000  0.000
x3  1.078 -1.406  0.543  0.000  0.000  0.000

# b) with cluster-variable
model <- '
fw =~ y1 + 1*y2 + y3
fw ~ x1 + x2 + x3
'
fit3c <- sem(model, data = Demo.twolevel, cluster = "cluster")
summary(fit3c, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)

lavResiduals(fit3c, zstat = TRUE, se = TRUE) #does not work
residuals (fit3c, type= "cor.bentler")

Output:

lavResiduals(fit3, zstat = TRUE, se = TRUE)#does not work
Fehler in Q %*% ACOV.obs[[g]] :
verlangt numerische/komplexe Matrix/Vektor-Argumente

It seems that lavaan does not compute the statistics. I can still obtain the unstandardized residuals (but now, he gives $mean in the output:
residuals (fit3o, type= "cor.bentler")

Output:

residuals (fit3o, type= "cor.bentler")
$type
[1] "cor.bentler"
$cov
y1     y2     y3     x1     x2     x3
y1  0.079
y2  0.016 -0.081
y3  0.075 -0.074  0.000
x1  0.025 -0.032  0.015  0.000
x2  0.026 -0.030  0.011  0.000  0.000
x3  0.011 -0.015  0.007  0.000  0.000  0.000
$mean
y1 y2 y3 x1 x2 x3
0  0  0  0  0  0

My question is: How can I obtain the standardized residuals for the model with clustered data? At least, how can I obtain the corrected standard errors to manually compute the standardized residuals? (To my knowledge, the formula would be: unstandardized residual/corrected standard error).
Kindly, Marcus
PS: R-version: 4.2.0, lavaan-version: 0.6-17

What's wrong with resid(fit3, type = "standardized")? See help("lavaan").

Thanks for the hint, this doesn't work either. Same error message:
Fehler in Q %*% ACOV.obs[[g]] :
verlangt numerische/komplexe Matrix/Vektor-Argumente
it has something to do with the fact that the cluster-corrected standard errors are not (or cannot be) extracted

R 4.4.1, lavaan 0.6-17. I cannot reproduce the error, it might have something to do with the version of R, base package Matrix has changed and errors may occur. packageVersion("Matrix") returns ‘1.6.5’. Time to update R?

Thanks again, Rui. Updated everything. But still the same error message (see above). Package "Matrix" is now 1.7.0, lavaan 0.6.18, R 4.4.1.
Very strange, did you get an output of the standardized res?

No, I didn't get the standardized residuals, I got the same error as you did. Maybe try to contact maintainer("lavaan")?

Thanks, I wrote about it to Yves and Terrence.

Yves opened an issue on Github concerning standardized residuals with cluster-variable: https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/issues/378
